# How get current process image file full name in filter driver?

Tags: c++, c, process, driver, filter-driver

In filter driver I can call `IoGetCurrentProcess` to get an `PEPROCESS` structure, and than call `PsGetProcessImageFileName` to get file name.

My questions is how I can get **full** name of the process image file?

Comment: Related link http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=109252

Comment: This looks like a winapi question.  If so, then surely it is also a C++ question (if any language-specific tag at all is relevant), not a C question.  Update your tags appropriately.

Comment: filter driver I can write in C not in C++.

Comment: You actually can use certain constructs from C++, however, you have to be careful – http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=490. Some time ago, I heard an opinion saying that kernel programming is difficult enough even wihtout problems possibly caused by C++ usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here](https://projects.honeynet.org/svn/capture-hpc/capture-hpc/tags/2.5/capture-client/KernelDrivers/CaptureKernelDrivers/ProcessMonitor/CaptureProcessMonitor.c) I found full code like @Martin Drab code

**EDIT**: new fixed code

```
NTSTATUS
GetProcessImageName(
    PEPROCESS eProcess,
    PUNICODE_STRING* ProcessImageName
    )
{
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    ULONG returnedLength;
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL;

    PAGED_CODE(); // this eliminates the possibility of the IDLE Thread/Process

    if (eProcess == NULL)
    {
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_1;
    }

    status = ObOpenObjectByPointer(eProcess,
        0, NULL, 0, 0, KernelMode, &hProcess);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("ObOpenObjectByPointer Failed: %08x\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    if (ZwQueryInformationProcess == NULL)
    {
        UNICODE_STRING routineName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"ZwQueryInformationProcess");

        ZwQueryInformationProcess =
            (QUERY_INFO_PROCESS)MmGetSystemRoutineAddress(&routineName);

        if (ZwQueryInformationProcess == NULL)
        {
            DbgPrint("Cannot resolve ZwQueryInformationProcess\n");
            status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
            goto cleanUp;
        }
    }

    /* Query the actual size of the process path */
    status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess,
        ProcessImageFileName,
        NULL, // buffer
        0,    // buffer size
        &returnedLength);

    if (STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH != status) {
        DbgPrint("ZwQueryInformationProcess status = %x\n", status);
        goto cleanUp;
    }

    *ProcessImageName = kmalloc(returnedLength);

    if (ProcessImageName == NULL)
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
        goto cleanUp;
    }

    /* Retrieve the process path from the handle to the process */
    status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess,
        ProcessImageFileName,
        *ProcessImageName,
        returnedLength,
        &returnedLength);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) kfree(*ProcessImageName);

cleanUp:

    ZwClose(hProcess);

    return status;
}

FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
PostCreate(
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_opt_ PVOID CompletionContext,
    _In_ FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags
    )
{
    PUNICODE_STRING pni = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

    status = GetProcessImageName(IoThreadToProcess(Data->Thread), &pni);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("ProcessName = %ws\n", pni->Buffer);
        kfree(pni);
    }
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("GetProcessImageName status = %x\n", status);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The leak fixed.

Comment: No. I see code paths that do not close the handle. When the buffer allocation fails, or when the first call of `ZwQueryInformationProcess` returns something different from STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH. Some other error paths seem not to be handled correctly (if `MmGetSystemRoutineAddress` fails to get the address of `ZwQueryInformationProcess`, if `PsLookupProcessByProcessId` fails...). Some of them result in returning an error NTSTATUS code but I think it is more of a lucky coincidence than author's inention.

Comment: Thank you very much, repaired again.

Comment: If the last call to `ZwQueryInformationProcess` inside `GetProcessImageName` fails, the `pni` buffer is not freed.

Comment: The leak fixed.

Comment: Hmm, the code looks OK to me now, although I prefer my version above :-).

Comment: Just had to replace `kmalloc(size)` with `ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, size)` and `kfree(pni)` with `ExFreePool(pni)`. Worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ZwQueryInformationProcess` with the information class of 27. THe following code uses this routine to obtain the full image file name from process' handle.

```
NTSTATUS GetProcessNameByHandle(_In_ HANDLE ProcessHandle, _Out_ PUNICODE_STRING *Name)
{
    ULONG retLength = 0;
    ULONG pniSize = 512;
    PUNICODE_STRING pni = NULL;
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

    do {
        pni = (PUNICODE_STRING)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(PagedPool, pniSize, POOL_TAG);
        if (pni != NULL) {
            status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(ProcessHandle, 27, pni, pniSize, &retLength);
            if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
              ExFreePoolWithTag(pni, POOL_TAG); 
              pniSize *= 2;
            }
        } else status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
        *Name = pni;

    return status;
}
```

You can obtain the process handle by the following ways:

- `ObOpenObjectByPointer`, you need process' EPROCESS address (`PsLookupProcessByProcessId` may help).
- `ZwOpenProcess` – youn need to know PID of the target process.

However, using this code in every invocation of your minifilter's pre/post callback can be quite time-consuming. I solve this problem by caching process names in a hash table that uses PID as a key. Notify routines (`PsSetXXXNotifyRoutine(Ex)`) may prove very useful when building and managing such a table.

Comment: Do you need to free `Name` after calling `GetProcessNameByHandle`?

Comment: I think you need to call `ExFreePool` in your caller func.