# Uninitialized LPWSTR Error While Using GetProcessImageFileNameW

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, driver

I am trying to use GetProcessImageFileNameW in a Windows kernel driver.

```
    LPWSTR path[MAX_PATH];
    if(GetProcessImageFileNameW(hProcess, path, MAX_PATH) == 0)
    {
        DbgPrint("Can't get the process image name");
        return;
    }
```

But when I build there is a compiler error "Using uninitialized memory 'path'"

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please include the complete error message.  You might like to read [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry. But Can `GetProcessImageFileNameW` be called in kernel mode? And [There is a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348630/how-get-current-process-image-file-full-name-in-filter-driver) Which supplied a solution getting current process image file full name in driver.

Answer (score 5):

`LPWSTR` is a single `wchar_t*` pointer. So `LPWSTR path[MAX_PATH];` is creating an array of `wchar_t*` pointers.

However, `GetProcessImageFileNameW()` takes an `LPWSTR` parameter, where the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamew) says:

> lpImageFileName
>
> A **pointer to a buffer** that receives the full path to the executable file.

That means `GetProcessImageFileNameW()` wants a pointer to an array of `wchar_t` characters, which it will then fill as needed.

An array *decays* into a pointer to its 1st element. So, you are passing a `wchar_t**` where a `wchar_t*` is expected.  I'm surprised you are not getting a compiler error about a type mismatch, rather than an error about uninitialized memory.

Try this instead:

```cpp
WCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {};
if (!GetProcessImageFileNameW(hProcess, path, MAX_PATH))
{
    DbgPrint("Can't get the process image name");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, but it steal not working. I am reminding that I am building a Windows driver and a regular user mode program.

Comment: "*it steal not working*" - in what way exactly? Be more specific.